# SQL Informix advanced query

Tags: sql, select, window-functions, informix

Let me try to explain what I want to do with my data. Structure of my data is as follows:

I have 3 columns: `date`, `id`, and `stage`. Stages can be different numbers, but I'm interested in showing specific transition of some id from `stage` `-1` to `stage` `1`. Please see the example below.

1. I have an `id` that was in `stage` `-1`, then transited to stage `1`, and went back to stage `-1` later. Whenever the transition from `-1` to `1` is made, I want that `id`.
2. Here, I have transition from `-1` to `3`, and that is not what interest me.
3. Here, transition is made, and this `id` is what I want to be shown.
4. Here, we have transition from `1` to `-1`, and that is not what I want.

Data:

```
    #1   date            id                     stage
        2018-12-31      520000000001354292      -1
        2019-09-30      520000000001354292       1
        2019-12-31      520000000001354292      -1
    
    
    #2  2018-12-31      520000000001435675      -1
        2019-03-31      520000000001435675      -1
        2019-06-30      520000000001435675       3
        
        
    #3  2018-12-31      520000000003156164      -1
        2019-03-31      520000000003156164      -1
        2018-12-31      520000000003161014      -1
        2019-03-31      520000000003161014       1


   #4  2018-12-31       520500000002472437      1
       2019-03-31       520500000002472437     -1
       2019-06-30       520500000002472437     -1
       2019-09-30       520500000002472437      2
```

My desired output is:

```
520000000001354292    
520000000003156164
```

I hope that I explained this clear enough.

Also, after this, i want to show transition from either `-1` and `1` to `stage` `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lag()`:

```
select distinct id
from (
    select t.*, lag(stage) over(partition by id order by date) lag_stage
    from mytable t
) t
where lag_stage = -1 and stage = 1
```

This brings all `id`s that have at least one transition from `-1` to `1`.

> Also, after this, i want to show transition from either -1 and 1 to stage 3.

You can easily adapt the query to fit that use case as well. Just change the final `where` clause to:

```
where lag_stage in (-1, 1) and stage = 3
```